# wafv2 webacl cloudformation gets error when I tried to attach the rulegroup I created

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-waf

I wrote this cloudformation

and it keeps giving me this error

Error reason: A reference in your rule statement is not valid., field: RULE, parameter: Statement (Service: Wafv2, Status Code: 400, Request ID: 8f88058f-556e-4fec-baf2-9a84d0353bbe, Extended Request ID: null)

has anyone seen this error before
?
Thank you

```
      {
        "Name": "Rule",
        "Priority": 1,
        "Action": {
          "Block": {}
        },
        "VisibilityConfig": {
          "SampledRequestsEnabled": true,
          "CloudWatchMetricsEnabled": true,
          "MetricName": "customrule"
        },
       "Statement": {
                        "RuleGroupReferenceStatement": {
                            "Arn": { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "TestRuleGroup", "Arn" ]
            
          }
        }
      }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

you should add below in your code when you reference a rule group
The field is needed even if you don't want to override it, you specify "none" as per the docs.

```
OverrideAction:
  None: {}
```

Comment: If you are using Terraform, you have to add code similar to this:-

override_action {
         none {}
}